# BotBuilder TypeError: builder.ConsoleConnector is not a constructor

Tags: node.js, botframework

I'm following the official quick start of Microsoft Bot Builder(SDK v3) for NodeJs:
 [Create a bot with the Bot Builder SDK for Node.js](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/nodejs/bot-builder-nodejs-quickstart?view=azure-bot-service-3.0)

1- I made a new project with

> npm init

2- then

> npm install --save botbuilder

3- then I created a new file "app.js"

```
var builder = require('botbuilder');

var connector = new builder.ConsoleConnector().listen();
var bot = new builder.UniversalBot(connector, function (session) {
session.send("You said: %s", session.message.text);
});
```

But when I run "node app.js" the following error is thrown:

```
var connector = new builder.ConsoleConnector().listen();
            ^

TypeError: builder.ConsoleConnector is not a constructor
```

Could anyone help me, please?

My project structure:

[image]

Answer (score 26, accepted):

There is a mismatch between the documentation and the latest release of the **botbuilder** package (version 4.0.6) features / methods. Microsoft has changed some of the legacy features of the **botbuilder** npm package, but they haven't updated their doc yet!

The JavaScript code which is present in [Microsoft's Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/nodejs/bot-builder-nodejs-quickstart?view=azure-bot-service-3.0) won't work for the same reason!

Try with the botbuilder package version 3.13.1 , it will work perfectly.

To Install:

```
npm i -S botbuilder@3.13.1
```

And your piece of code will work!

Find the snapshots:

[image: code]

[image: package.json]

Cheers!!

Comment: @PrateekMehta: 