# Starting with Bot Framework botbuilder and get an Assertion Error

Tags: node.js, botframework

I am following the video course ["Creating Bots in the Microsoft Bot Framework Using Node.js"](https://mva.microsoft.com/en-US/training-courses/getting-started-with-bots-16759?l=Pfzej8HyC_4004668937) 
and **having problems running the first app.js file**.

I installed botbuilder, restify and did the `npm install --save-dev @types/restify` command as shown in the course.

When i try to run the app.js file I faced first the errorType that is solved [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52604280/botbuilder-typeerror-builder-consoleconnector-is-not-a-constructor) with downloading the botbuilder package version 3.13.1.

---

But now I get another error which I cant solve:

```
assert.js:350
    throw err;

AssertionError [ERR_ASSERTION]: The first character of a path should be `/` or `*`
```

Code-Scrrenshots are in the links: [Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6FRXo.png), [ErrorCode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GfIW4.png)

Does anyone have a similiar problem or knows how to help me? I would be very thankful. :)

---

My guess is that there is something wrong with my `node_modules` folder where `assert.js` can be found!? But i dont know what to update, or if I change something in assert.js directly. Couldnt find any solution online.

Comment: What channel are you trying to connect thru? Web chat, emulator, or something else?

Comment: Two other things: One, can you double check the botbuilder version you are using? Two, you are using state store which is deprecated. Please setup your bot using memory storage, table storage, cosmos db, or some other solution. You can read about setting up here (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/nodejs/bot-builder-nodejs-state?view=azure-bot-service-3.0). I was able to get the bot working using your setup and SDK version without any hitches.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `server.post('api/messages', con...` 
do 
`server.post('/api/messages', con...`

The first character of a path should be `/` or `*`

Answer (score 0):

typically this error occurs because in your route you forgot to add the "/" to instantiate your route.

Ex: `/routes/libs/hello.ts`

This would be a recommended way for you to instantiate your routes in your code.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Your answers should bring new informations to questions, but it seems that there already is an answer with what you've posted here.